# Component rendering multiple times without any reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was facing multiple re-renders and thus to find the issue I commented every line of code and at last found the constant definition causing re-render:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  console.log('render') // logs 4 times
  const myRef = useRef(null)
  return <h1>hello</h1>
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  console.log('render') // logs 2 times
  return <h1>hello</h1>
}
```

I know strict mode renders the component 2 times. But, why just defining `myRef` constant causing re-render further 2 times?

I just tried `React.memo` as comment, but it still renders 4 times:

```
export default React.memo(MyComponent)
```

Okay, I just tested using the same code in App.js and it only logged 2 times. So, it seems to be parent component issue. But my question is why in the child component without having anything causing renders additional 2 times just defining the variable?

Comment: if you are concerned about too many re-renders you can use `React.memo()` to ensure it only updates once something has changed

Comment: useRef is commonly used to avoid re-rendering... so I am assuming you have something else going on that we don't have eyes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you and React docs said:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
>   can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
>   This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
> - Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

It does not include `useRef` but it actually should be on this list because it uses same underlying mechanism as `useState`

`React.memo` won't help here because what causes re-render is `React.StrictMode` special mechanism to check side effects and other stuff, so it ignores `memo` and similar techniques.

What's interesting here that if you add `useRef` in Parent component it will invoke function body 2 times, but its children (if they don't use `useRef`) are gonna be invoked only once.

All this stuff only works for development mode, so in production there won't be any *intentional* double invocations and other things but they can still happen unintentionally.

Comment: Ofcourse, I should not be worried about production mode. But, only concern is why even in strict mode, only just defining variable cause further render?

Comment: React needs to know if your component have some potentially dangerous side effects or not and it uses double-invoking to check for them and warn you. Every component which uses any features listed above is checked for side-effects.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.